# saving long strings containing quotes to a hidden input

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a long string which contians anything (single quote, double quote ...). Now I want to save this string in a hidden input and using it in my JavaScript code. How can I save this string in a hidden input?

Answer (score 1):

I have misunderstood the question first time.

All you need to do is to encode your variable for html. You can have a look on how to do it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx

A basic use would be

```
myString = "asd\"ewr'2";
myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString);
```

And then in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" value="@{ @myEncodedString }">
```

Comment: I am using Code behind and I think I have to encode my string because it contains quotation marks.

Comment: Can you show me how you pass the string to javascript? Once you manage to put the string into a javascript variable, then you can do what I suggested ...

Comment: I just get it from value of the hidden input. $("#myhidden").val();

Comment: What I mean is where do you get that string from, how do you "bring" that string to javascript?

Comment: I am using code behind to read it from a file and put it to the hidden input

Comment: So you're doing the opposite ... You put it in the hidden input using some server-side technology and then you want to access it with javascript using `$("#myhidden").val();`, right?

Comment: THanks, Do I need to decode it when I access it from JS?

Comment: No decoding is needed if you want to print it to page, for example. But it depends on what you want to do with